# jQuery hover staying active when scrolling down/up page

Tags: jquery, thumbnails

I have a wordpress site with a plugin that is used for the slider/thumbs for images.  When I hover over the image, the thumbnails appear, then when I'm off the image, they disappear.   The issue I have is when I scroll down the page, the thumbnails reappear and do not disappear.   It's somehow binded the hover to the page scroll.

Here is the script that is hiding/showing the thumbnails:

```
initAutoHide:function(){// Init Auto Hide
                    HideID = setInterval(methods.hideItems, parseInt(AutoHideTime));

                    $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container', Container).hover(function(){
                        methods.showItems();
                    }, function(){
                        HideID = setInterval(methods.hideItems, parseInt(AutoHideTime));
                    });
                },
                showItems:function(){// Show Items
                    clearInterval(HideID);
                    ItemsHidden = false;

                    if (imageLoaded){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_NavigationLeft', Container).css('display', 'block');
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_NavigationRight', Container).css('display', 'block');
                    }

                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'top'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-top': 0}, 600);
                    }
                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'right'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left': $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container', Container).width()-$('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).width()}, 600);
                    }
                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'bottom'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-top': $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container', Container).height()-$('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).height()}, 600);
                    }
                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'left'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left': 0}, 600);
                    }
                    methods.showCaption();
                },
                hideItems:function()
                {
                    clearInterval(HideID);
                    ItemsHidden = true;

                    $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_NavigationLeft', Container).css('display', 'none');
                    $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_NavigationRight', Container).css('display', 'none');

                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'top'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-top': 0-$('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).height()}, 600);
                    }
                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'right'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left': $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container', Container).width()}, 600);
                    }
                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'bottom'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-top': $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_Container', Container).height()}, 600);
                    }
                    if (ThumbnailsPosition == 'left'){
                        $('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left': 0-$('.DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer', Container).width()}, 600);
                    }
                    methods.hideCaption();
                }
              },
```

Can anyone recommend the best thing to do to kill the hover when not directly over the image?

To add on to this, here is how I could hide when scrolling:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
$(".DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer").hide();

 });
```

Now if the user hovers back over the image, how can I bring it back?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue in the past, I think it has something to do with the scrolling not triggering the `mouseout()` event, because technically the mouse hasn't moved. Sadly this is done at browser level - try hovering over a link on SO then using the arrow keys to scroll, the link will stay in it's hovered state until you move the mouse.

Work around would be to hide all images on page scroll, maybe more elegant to hide all other images when opening a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I found a way to make the container hide when the user scrolls, but the only issue is I don't know how to add the logic to bring it back if they hover.  Here is what I did to hide on page scroll:

        $(document).scroll(function(){
  $("#DOP_ThumbnailGallery_ThumbnailsContainer").hide();
});

Do you know how I can make it reappear when the user hovers?